# Play Framework - Generates Code for Routes Configuration

Tags: scala, playframework, routes

I recently started to learn Play framework 2.6 with Scala. I understand that Play compiles and generates code, such as [reverse-routing](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaRouting#Reverse-routing), for my route config file in `conf/routes`, but I'm having hard time to understand where and how it generates them.

As of my observation, I found 4 generated files under `target/scala-2.12/routes` directory:

- Routes.scala
- RoutesPrefix.scala
- routes.java
- ReverseRoutes.scala

What is the purpose/role of the above 4 files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it allows you to generate reverse routes basing on `conf/routes` file.

You have a controller:

```
package controllers

class SomethingController {

  def doThings(param: String): Future[String] = ???
}
```

and `routes` file

```
GET /something/:param  controllers.SomethingController.doThings(param: String)
```

Then play will generate classes that

- will be wiring the query to the controllers - in `Routes.scala` you can see the code that will pass query to the right controller. It is used by Play application, you won't have to deal with this file,
- allow you to generate the URL for a particular action - `routes.java`, `ReverseRoutes.scala`

  `controllers.routes.SomethingController.doThings("something") // Call`
- prefix is an utility that allows you to add prefix to all routes at once - if you e.g. wanted to add `/api` everywhere between host and the URI, then it is possible because a prefix was made to be configurable (e.g. by settings `play.http.context=/api` in `application.conf`). You probably won't have to use it directly.

Comment: According to your answer, the only file I need to deal is `ReverseRoutes.scala`. Could you tell me when and what I want to use this file for?

Comment: It generates the `Call` object that you can use to: generate the URI of a request, if you have an implicit request in scope then an absolute URL to the request, but also you might feed it with body and headers and use to make an actual request. It is useful in tests or if you have several apps with aggregated reverse routes (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/AggregatingReverseRouters) then you can quite reliably make requests from one site to the other.